# Whats the way to define a test for a Grape API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rspec, ruby-grape

I'm trying to define a test environment to make request programmatically to my Grape API.

I have the main API file into /app/api/services/v1.rb and i created a folder called requests into the spec path that have a file with this content for testing:

```
describe Services::V1 do
  describe "GET /v1/users/:id" do
    it "returns a user by id" do
      user = User.create!
      get "/api/users/#{user.id}"
      expect(response.body).to eq user.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

The API have a path defined for the users resource but i have an error meaning that the Servicesnamespace is "uninitialized constant Services (NameError)"

I've added config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request, file_path: /spec/api/ into the spec_helper but i think that i'm misunderstanding the Grape doc related with that.

> "You may want your API code to go into app/api - you can match that
>   layout under spec by adding the following in spec/spec_helper.rb.
>
> RSpec.configure do |config|   config.include
>   RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request, file_path:
>   /spec/api/ end"

Any help to make things work is appreciated. I'm a newbie with this technologies setup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the resource not the api version.

```
describe "ExampleApi::V1::Regions" do

  describe "GET /api/v1/regions/{id}" do
    context "without data" do
      it "should return a status code 404" do
        get "/api/v1/regions/100000000", nil, { 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token.token}"}
        expect(response.status).to eq 404
      end

      it "should return an empty array" do
        get "/api/v1/regions/100000000", nil, { 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token.token}"}
        expect(json['error']['code']).to eq(404)
      end
    end

    context "with data" do
      it 'returns a status code 200' do
        get "/api/v1/regions", nil, { 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token.token}"}
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end

      it 'returns a region' do
        region1 = Fabricate(:region)
        get "/api/v1/regions/#{region1.id}", nil, { 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token.token}"}
        expect(json["id"]).to eq(region1.id)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

On this example, the Authorization header is used in case you're using Authentication (on this case Oauth2).

There is also a helper or json, you can create a file on support folder:

```
module Requests
  module JsonHelpers
    def json
      @json ||= JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
  end
end
```

on rails_helper.rb add:

```
# Just if the tests are in spec/api folder
config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request, file_path: /spec\/api/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you add `config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request, file_path: /spec/api/` in rails_helper.rb, it means you should put your api specs in `/spec/api/`, not `/spec/requests/`.
2. You should add `require 'rails_helper'` in your `/spec/api/services/v1/regious_spec.rb`